# How to get a history of Google verification codes

Tags: history, google-accounts, verification

Yesterday I got Google verification code -- the problem is I didn't take any action that would require this. So I would like to check the history of verification codes -- see what what reason they were created ([Google lists several possible reasons](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3367674?hl=en)) and if they were verified (i.e. does the intruder used them successfully).

I checked the history but I can only see the list of the devices used (which is correct in my case), but no verification codes history. So how to get it?